Not displaying color properly on TFT display
I'm using STM32 Nucleo LO73RZ with a 128*128 TFT display. The colors do not  appear correct, and there is flicker in the screen. When the text is yellow, it appears blue. When the text is blue, it appears red. How to solve this? I use 4MBits/s as SPI baudrate.
I tried changing the baudrate and shaking the jumper wires. Not any progress.

Your display probably has a display controller that probably has a register you can write to that selects between different modes (e.g. TN vs VA), which changes how the colours appear. Or maybe you're sending the pixels in the wrong order (RGB vs BRG). Hard to tell since you haven't given us much information.

Its also flikering white background so fast
